# SharePoint JSLink or Inject Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jsom, jslink

I have an SharePoint hosted app with a list(test). On the Lists/test/AllItems.aspx  is there a way to inject JavaScript file with referenc to thirds party Javascript files like datables etc .

Issue with JSLink
When i use JSLINK i can format it but i can't

a) Inject a third party javascript file like datables

b) Inject a custom Javascript File to inject Navigation to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign multiple files to the jslink property of the webpart. It can also be used to load on-crs javascript files like jquery. For example:
~sitecollection/style library/scripts/jQuery.js|~sitecollection/style library/scripts/my-csr-file.js

Answer (score 1):

JSLinks on SPOnline can handle any https reference

I pulled this from working code.

```
    var field = web.get_availableFields().getByTitle( fieldTitle );
    context.load(field);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        field.set_jsLink(jsLinkUrl);
        field.updateAndPushChanges(true);
        context.executeQueryAsync();
    });
```

BUT ... I don't do SP Hosted Apps, execute this (as Bookmarklet) with an admin account